# Width of a div element in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, width, decimal, floating

Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob1E9.jpg
Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bdw5.jpg

Well, I only have a `<div>` in my `<body>`, here's the code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
```

Together with some simple styles:

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 692px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid green;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

When opening "**Inspect element**" in Google Chrome, I have a weird values with numbers after decimal point for both `width` and `margin` in the box-model (691.989 for `width` and 373.281 for `margin`). This issue however doesn't occur in FireFox.
Providing pictures below:

Could someone please explain to me why this occurs and how can I fix this? It's rather annoying when you add more `divs` and the `widths` are all over the place. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, I get exact values in both browsers. Have you tried updating Chrome?

Comment: Go to the setting icon in the top-right of your inspector and try "Restore defaults and reload"

Comment: in my Chrome it's perfect

Comment: just checked with your code. no error found. http://jsfiddle.net/mFQq7/2/

Comment: Thank you for all your responds. It appears that `<body>` element, which should be taking all of it's width takes 1454.545 as well, this is so odd.

@MichaelRader I've tried what you suggested, didn't help.
@СърГеоргиДемирев Version 35.0.1916.114 m Google Chrome is up to date.

Comment: P.S: I've tried to load the page without a local server, it appears that's where the problem lies since now it's working properly...

Comment: @Arno you may need a css style reset in your stylesheet as all browsers do behave differently. Try this

http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/